# Shortcut for move line up and down in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I select a row in the `Edit` menu of Google Sheet in web browser there is a nice functionality `Move line up` and `Move line down`.

The problem comes when I need to move a line 10 lines up or down: I need to open the menu a lot of times...

Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut? I would greatly simplify the things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could assign a keyboard shortcut, which would run a saved macro.

I tested by recording a macro of using the Edit menu to move a row up one line.  Then by editing the macro, I could change the "1" to a "10", to move the row up ten lines.  The macro looks like this.

```
function MoveRowUp10Rows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().moveRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow() - 10);
};
```

Depending on the nature of your editing work, you could create several, to move a row up 3,5,or 10 rows, or whatever you need, each with a keyboard shortcut.

Or you could enhance the macro to add a pop-up prompt for the number of rows you want to move - up or down.  (Search here on SO to find how to add user input to a script/macro...)

Note the above macro works even if you've just selected one cell on a row - no need to select the whole row.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to move 1 row up/down for X positions in one iteration in Google Sheets.

Instead of moving one row X times down we can select X rows below the row we need to move and move them up one time.

Answer (score 0):

1. select the block.
2. alt+shift+ up or down